# PHP - Read a text file and use each line value sequentially in POST requests

Tags: php, twitter, foreach

Hello :) I apologize in advance if this is really dumb, but I've been trying to figure it out for a week and now I'm about to explode :D

I have a list of 200 ID numbers in a text file, each are separated by a newline. I want to use PHP to use each line, one by one, as a variable in a POST request. I can use this code to send the first line, by specifying the number of characters to include from the file:

```
    $IDfile = "file.txt";
    $fh = fopen($IDfile, 'r');
    $ID = fread($fh, 18);
    fclose($fh);
```

Then I can use the $ID variable in the POST. But this is only good for the first line, since there are 18 characters in the line, but there are 199 more lines.

I can also print all the lines in the file with a foreach, but this won't help with the POST requests:

```
    $IDfile = "file.txt";
    $lines = file($IDfile);
    foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)
    {
    echo $line;
    echo "<br>";
    }
```

So, here is the full script of my POST request, to send a "destroy tweet" command to the Twitter API 1.1 - The $ID variable is the one I want to replace using every line in the text file sequentially:

```
    require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
    include('apikeys.php');

    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/destroy/" .$ID . ".json";
    $requestMethod = 'POST';

    $postfields = array(
    );

    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->setPostfields($postfields)
    ->performRequest();
```

So how do I do it? How can I get each line sequentially from the text file, and then use the single line value as a variable in the POST request, until each has been read?

This is probably way out of my league lol, but I am determined to learn this, and any help or direction would be so very gratefully received :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if i am right your must contain the `id` field

```
<?php
  require_once( "TwitterAPIExchange.php" );
  include( "apikeys.php" );

  $url    = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/destroy/%s.json";
  $lines  = file( "file.txt" );
  $post   = array(
    "id"  =>  null
  );

  foreach( $lines as $line ) {
    $line = trim( $line );
    $post["id"] = $line;

    $twitter  = new TwitterAPIExchange( $settings );
    $response = $twitter->buildOauth( sprintf( $url, $line ), "POST" )
                        ->setPostfields( $post )
                        ->performRequest();

    $response = json_decode( $response );
    if ( !$response ) {
      echo "Empty response";
      break;
    }

    var_dump( $response );
  }
?>
```

Comment: Oooh it's working :))) I changed $post = array to $postfields = array because i t was giving errors, but now, it's working great!!!

Comment: Thank you SO much!!! Now I'm going to figure out what's happening in your code. So it's sending a single ID as a POST variable in a form, but from the text file?

Comment: oops, sorry my mistake i forgot to change `$postfields` :)
For more information check this link https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/destroy/%3Aid
Code updated check now :)

Comment: No its sending to all `ID` from the text file.
I didn't used Twitter API yet, so don't know about that very much :(

Comment: Ah I think I understand, I was adding the ID into the $url but it should go to $postfields because there is more than 1 value. I will play with this more :) Thank you, you are cool!! I can't UpVote the answer because low reputation, but I want to :)

Comment: Its okay :) happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fopen` to read the file and then inside the loop you can create the URL and send a POST request, like so:

```
$f = fopen("file.txt", "r");

while(!feof($f)) { 

    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/destroy/" . trim($f) . ".json";
    $requestMethod = 'POST';

    $postfields = array(
    );

    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->setPostfields($postfields)
    ->performRequest();
}
```

Comment: Hello Amal, thanks for replying. I had the same issue with this solution as I did with Binary's below. The script runs, but no Tweets are deleted. I had a thought it could be that the POST action has to complete, and a response received before the next POST request can be sent. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should help you solve that issue

```
  $IDfile = "file.txt";
    $lines = file($IDfile);
    foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)
    {
    echo sending request for $line;

    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/destroy/" .$line . ".json";
    $requestMethod = 'POST';

    $postfields = array(
    );

    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->setPostfields($postfields)
    ->performRequest();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Binary, I took out the "echo sending request for $line;"and the script runs but there is no response from Twitter, and there are no deleted Tweets. I had a thought that there may need to be the response first, and then the next POST request to be sent. Does that make sense?